# acpi device versus platform device

Tags: drivers, kernel, acpi

We have a device defined in the ACPI table (bios).
Under kernel 4.* This device is registered in the platform device path: /sys/bus/platform/devices/...

Under kernel 3.10 the same device is not anymore registered at the same location but under /sys/bus/acpi/devices.

For this reason  our platform driver does not get initialized since the platform_driver_register() method does not find a match with a device (in the platform device list).

Does anyone know how does the kernel decide to put a device into the platform device list?

Thanks in advance,
Serge